# TFS Source Control returns HTTP Code 302 with remote user

Tags: version-control, tfs

I have a remote developer connected to my TFS via the internet.  When he attempts to do a GET from source control, he fails to get a number of files with error messages as this:

D:\CaseTrakker\CaseTrakker_v6_0\CaseTrakker\CaseTrakker.ObjectModel\Framework\Factories\Value\LookupValueViewModelFactory.cs: Please contact your administrator.  There was an error contacting the server.
Technical information (for administrator):
  HTTP code 302: Moved Temporarily

This does not happen for all files, but for many, and repeated retries does not resolve it.  I am at a complete loss.

Possibly germane, the way that I have published my TFS is to set up a rule in my firewall to route requests targetting `http://publicserver:8080/tfs` to `http://internalserver:8080/tfs`.  Since this error seems to have to do with redirection, that might be some or all of the issue.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

David Mullin
IMA Technologies

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth getting the external developer to upgrade to the latest [Update 3 CTP of VS 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/05/07/visual-studio-2012-3-update-3-go-live-ctp-is-now-available.aspx) as there was a fix in it to handle retries better on downloads.

However, you'll probably have more luck if you configure it so that your TFS server is accessible over the same fully qualified domain name both internally and externally (internally resolving to the internal IP - externally resolving to your external IP).  Check out this word document for more information (http://www.christiano.ch/common/documents/Exposing_Team_Foundation_Server_to_the_Internet.docx) or take a look at the [Pro TFS 2012 book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118314093).